Algebraic path connecting specific elements in $\mathbf{GL}_{3}(\mathbb{Z})$
I was reading Motivic symmetric spectra by J. F. Jardine. In the proof of lemma 3.13, he tried to show the following:
the permutation matrix $\mathbf{A}$ corresponding to (1, 2, 3), that is, $$
    \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}
    $$
is algebraically path connected with the identity matrix within $\mathbf{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$.
In other words, there exists a path
$$
f: \mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}} \to \mathbf{GL}_{3, \mathbb{Z}}
$$
such that $f(0) = \mathbf{Id}$ and $f(1) = \mathbf{A}$.
I tried to unwrap the definition into polynomial equations, but I found the equation is so long to write down.
Here is what I have done. First note that such an f corresponds to an invertible matrix $\mathbf{A}(t)$ of which coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}[t]$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
    a(t) & b(t) & c(t)\\
    d(t) & e(t) & f(t)\\
    g(t) & h(t) & i(t)
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Since $\mathbb{A}(t) \in \mathbf{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z}[t])$, it’s determinant must be an invertible element in $\mathbb{Z}$ and therefore $1$, since $det(\mathbf{A}(0)) = 1$.
Now consider the equation $\mathbf{A}(0) = \mathbf{Id}$, we find that
$$
a = 1+ta’, b = tb’, …, e = 1+te’, …, i = 1+ti’
$$
Next consider the equation $\mathbf{A}(1) = \mathbf{A}$, we have
$$
a’ = -1+(t-1)a’’, …, b’ = 1+(t-1)b’’, …, c’ = (t-1)c’’.
$$
What we get is then a very long equation.

I am surely missing context, but I struggle to see how any subset of $\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$ could be connected. Even if your proposal worked, having, e.g., $a=1+ta'$ would mean that for most values of $t$, $a$ is not an integer. Could you clarify how connectedness works in this case?

@CarlosSantiToledo Very basically, in algebraic geometry, there are some enhancements made so that $GL_3(\Bbb Z)$ doesn't mean exactly the same thing as "3x3 invertible matrices with coefficients in $\Bbb Z$". If you have not seen much algebraic geometry before, this post may not serve as the most hospitable introduction.

We don't want/require a map from the whole line, just some non-empty open subset. For example, set $g(t)=1-3t+3t^2$ and consider the open subset $U=D(g)$ inside $\mathbb A^1$. Then there is an algebraic map
$$ f\ \colon\ U \to \mathbf{GL}_3, \quad t \mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}1-t&t&0\\0&1-t&t\\t&0&1-t\end{bmatrix} $$
This is OK since $\det(f(t))=(1-t)^3+t^3=g(t)$, which is invertible on $U$. Also, $f(0)=\mathbf{Id}$ and $f(1)=\mathbf A$.
In terms of co-ordinate algebras, $\mathbf{GL}_3$ is Spec of
$$ R = \mathbb Z[x_{ij},D]/(\det(x_{ij})D=1) \quad\textrm{where }1\leq i,j\leq3. $$
Our $U=D(g)$ above is Spec of $S=\mathbb Z[t,g(t)^{-1}]$, and our morphism comes from the algebra map
$$ \phi\ \colon\ R \to S, \quad x_{ij}\mapsto\begin{cases}1-t&j=i\\t&j=\sigma(i)\\0&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases} \quad\textrm{and}\quad D \mapsto g(t)^{-1}. $$

The path is used to show that these two points are A1-connected, why it’s enough to take an open of A1?

Lemma 3.13 in the article has the purpose to show that $(123)$ operates trivially on $T^{\otimes 3}$ with $T$ the cofiber of $\mathbb{G}_m^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{A}^3$ which has the consequence that one can use either non-symmetric spectra or symmetric spectra and they are both equivalent.
The group $\mathrm{GL}_3$ acts on $T$ in the obvious way and $(123)$ corresponds to the matrix (I use the transport)
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 &  0& 1 \\
 1& 0 &  0\\
 0&1  & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0  \\
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0  \\
 0&  0 & -1 \\
 0& 1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  0& 2 \\
 0& 1 & -2 \\
 0& 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
where all matrics on the RHS have the form $\operatorname{id} + N$ with $N$ a nilpotent matrix. The path that you want to find is simply given by multiplying paths $t \longmapsto \operatorname{id} + tN$, which is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1-t & t^2-t & 2t-2t^3+t^2 \\
t & 1-t^2 &t^2-3t+2t^3  \\
0 & t & -2t^2+1+t \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1-t & -t & 0  \\
t & 1+t & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0  \\
 0&  1-t & -t \\
 0&t & 1+t \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  0& 2t\\
 0& 1 & -2t \\
 0& 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$
This matrix belongs to $\mathrm{GL}_3$ because any matrix of the form $\operatorname{id} + tN$ has inverse of the form $\sum_{i = 0}^k (-t)^i N^i$ for sufficiently large $k$.

Took me a sec to figure out that you're referring to point-wise multiplication of paths, not to some algebraic analogue of path composition (which I don't think can exist?). Do you happen to know of a resource that digs into more detail on this notion of "algebraic path"? This question was my first time reading someone bring up the notion, so I'm wrapping my head around it. I did check the article, but the notion of path only comes up the one time. Probably worth its own MSE question, but I'm asking you first.

@DustanLevenstein Hi, The paper by Jardine is one the foundational articles for the $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy, which is studied intensively by Voevodsky. Basically, this theory combines techniques from both algebraic geometry and algebraic topology, and the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1$ plays the role of the unit interval $[0,1]$ in algebraic topology. Composing algebraic paths may not be a good notion; however, you can define $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy groups. Perhaps somewhere there are people studying what you may expect, you can ask a question on MO instead of MSE.

After brute force calculation, I find out such an $\mathbf{A}(t)$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
    -t^2+1 & t^4-3t^3+3t & 3t^2-3t\\
    0 & -t^2+1 & t\\
    t & 0 & -t^2+1
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
